# trying to build webkit from android externals

Tags: android, build, webkit

I've been trying to build Android WebKit from source (from here https://github.com/android/platform_external_webkit), but haven't had any success so far. I've run `make` and `ndk-build` from the root directory of my repo copy and from from the Source directory inside it, with the following results:

`make` from the root directory (makes sense, because there is no Makefile),

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

`make` from the /Source directory:

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/webkit/Source/JavaScriptGlue'
../Makefile.shared:2: ../../Makefile.shared: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `../../Makefile.shared'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/webkit/Source/JavaScriptGlue'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

`ndk-build` from root and ./Source:

```
Android NDK: Could not find application project directory !    
Android NDK: Please define the NDK_PROJECT_PATH variable to point to it.    
<NDK>/build/core/build-local.mk:130: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
```

Can anyone advise as to what I'm doing wrong? I've read mention of Android needing to be compiled as a whole, but since this is 'external', I thought it would compile standalone. Am I wrong about that? Or is there some configuration step I've missed? Or anything else?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't allow you to get a build fully working, I suspect you did the same as me and cloned to a folder called webkit.

If you rename that to jni and then run `ndk-build` from the folder containing jni, it does at least get past the problem you mention. I now get the error:

```
jni/Android.mk:314: external/stlport/libstlport.mk: No such file or directory
Android NDK: Trying to define local module 'webcore' in jni/Source/WebKit/Android.mk.
Android NDK: But this module was already defined by jni/Source/WebKit/Android.mk.
/cygdrive/e/android-ndk-r7/build/core/build-module.mk:34: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.
```

I'm still trying to figure out how to solve this new error.

Comment: Yes, I did exactly that. I tried renaming my source folder to jni and was able to get to the same point you have and receive the same error. I got the libstlport.mk and associated by cloning from here: 

git://codeaurora.org/froyo-gb-dsds-7227.git/

Then I copied the stlport folder from inside the external folder from the repo into my jni directory.

The 314 error is gone, but it still errors out at webcore. I'm tired , but will look into this more tomorrow.